# Regular expressions in LoadImpact / Lua

Tags: lua, string-matching, lua-patterns

I am seeking to catch following keyword out of the source code in LoadImpact (Lua) and getting 'nil value'.

Keyword to capture - `sf6HxIvNKKsv1jD4`

From the body - `/product/392/form_key/sf6HxIvNKKsv1jD4/')">`

I tried this but getting a 'nil value' effor -

```
local key = string.match(body, 'form_key%/([^"]*)%/')
```

---

Thanks Avinash, hjpotter.

Basically I am trying to capture dynamic key after `form_key` (from the source code) in a variable and then replace the keyword in the script with that variable. This will make my script dynamic to accommodate changes in dynamic keywords happening in the appln.

For that I am using following code -

```
local pages = http.request_batch({ {"GET", "http://example.com/";, response_body_bytes=4096} })
local body = pages[1]['body']
local key = print(string.match(body, "form_key%/([^%/])%/"))
```

However I nil value is getting stored in the variable. Could you please suggest?

Comment: Note: Lua patterns aren't regexes. They're similar, but patterns are quite a bit weaker, to keep their implementation simple.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to capture alphanumerics from the (near) end part of your string, you can use the `$`:

```
local s = [[/product/392/form_key/sf6HxIvNKKsv1jD4/')">]]
local key = s:match "(%w+)/'%)\">$"
```

---

You are calling the `print` function. Since print doesn't return anything, you won't get the variable stored in the `key`.

Just use the following:

```
local key = body:match "form_key/([^/])/"
```

Answer (score 0):

The below regex would match the string which was just after to the string `form_key/` upto the next `/` symbol.

```
> print(string.match("/product/392/form_key/sf6HxIvNKKsv1jD4/')\">", ".*%/([^%/]*)%/"))
sf6HxIvNKKsv1jD4
```

**OR**

```
> print(string.match("/product/392/form_key/sf6HxIvNKKsv1jD4/')\">", "form_key%/([^%/]*)%/"))
sf6HxIvNKKsv1jD4
```

**Explanation:**

- In lua there is no lookahead or lookbehind. It supports grouping. `match` function would return the characters in the captured group.
- `form_key%/` On the input string, this pattern matches the string `form_key` followed by a literal `/`. In lua `%` does the same thing as `\`(escape character) does in other languages.
- `([^%/]*)` Captures any character not of `/` zero or more times.
- `%/` A literal `/` symbol.
- Finally, the captured characters are printed through `match` function.